# Can't detect why my loop is infinite

Tags: javascript, while-loop

```js
var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
guesses = prompt("guess a number between 1 and 100");
var scores = 0;
while (randomNum < 100) {
    if (guesses < randomNum) {
        console.log(" too low.. continue")
    } else if (guesses > randomNum) {
        console.log("too high ... continue ");
        score++;
    } else if (guesses === randomNum) {
        console.log("great ... that is correct!!")
    } else {
        console.log("game over ... your guess was right  " + scores + " times");
    }
}
```

I have been struggling with the while loop concept for some time now and in order to confront my fears I decided to practice with some tiny exercises like the one above.

Comment: `randomNum` and `guesses` only ever are assigned *one* value: and this is used in the only loop-termination condition. (The loop should probably 'end' when the correct number is guessed; is there a missing `break`? Should the code read in `guesses` again?)

Comment: `while (randomNum < 100)` -- that condition is always true, so the loop continues to be run

Comment: You need to generate a new `randomNum` INSIDE your while loop.

Comment: @jfriend00 While I agree that the post needed to be formatted, I don't think changing the indenting and moving braces around is the best idea.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ - I just put the code in an [automatic formatter](http://jsbeautifier.org/).  For the number of times there are poorly or completely unformatted code here on stack overflow, I'm not about to manually correct the formatting every time and try to discern the original coding style intent.  As far as I'm concerned if you post poorly formatted code here, we have a right to make it legible in whatever way is most expedient to us.  If the OP wants to change the formatting or whatever, they are free to do that.  At least it is readable now.

Comment: @jfriend00 * As far as I'm concerned if you post poorly formatted code here, we have a right to fix it in whatever way is expedient to us* I'll have to disagree with you on that.  What if you start removing errors or introducing them due to your personal formatting styles?

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ - Obviously, we should preserve the function of the original code.  The point is to make it readable.  Did I unintentionally change the function of the original code?  Has the OP objected in any way?  Is the solution to this question changed in any way because of the clarifying edits I made?  I'd rather have a practical discussion rather than a conceptual one.  I'm attempting to help newbies who post poorly formatted questions.  My alternative is to stop helping newbies and just closevote their question and move on.  Instead, I choose to help.

Answer (score 1):

You're not incrementing randomNum hence it will always stay in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize `randonNum` and `guesses` at the beginning of your code, but then you never change their values again.  So, once you go inside the `while` loop and the condition starts out to be false, then there is nothing inside the `while` loop to ever change the outcome of the comparison condition.  Thus, the condition is always false and you end up with an infinite loop.   Your loop structure boils down to this:

```
while (randomNum < 100) {
    // randomNum never changes
    // there is no code to ever break or return out of the loop
    // so loop is infinite and goes on forever
}
```

You can fix the problem by either putting a condition in the loop that will break out of the loop with a `break` or `return` or you can modify the value of `randomNum` in the loop such that eventually the loop will terminate on its own.

In addition, `guesses === randomNum` will never be true because `guesses` is a string and `randomNum` is a number so you have to fix that comparison too.

---

It's not 100% clear what you want to achieve, but if you're trying to have the user repeatedly guess the number until they get it right, then you need to put a `prompt()` inside the while loop and a break out of the while loop when they get it right or ask to cancel:

```
var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
var guess;
var score = 0;
while ((guess = prompt("guess a number between 1 and 100")) !== null) {
    // convert typed string into a number
    guess = +guess;
    if (guess < randomNum) {
        console.log(" too low.. continue")
    } else if (guess > randomNum) {
        console.log("too high ... continue ");
        score++;
    } else if (guess === randomNum) {
        console.log("great ... that is correct!!")
        console.log("score was: " + score);
        // when we match, stop the while loop
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ajakz - Did this provide an answer to your question?  Since you appear to be new here, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of whatever you thought was the best answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.

Answer (score 0):

the below line of code of your assign `randomNum` only one time hence it doesn't change

```
var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
```

so when you are trying to create the while loop the `randomNum` value remains same

try changing the `randomNum` value in the while loop

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you tried to achieve. Retry x number of times

```js
var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
var guesses;
var scores = 0;
var tries = 0
while (tries++ < 3) { // Loop if less than 3 tries, and increment
  guesses = prompt("guess a number between 1 and 100");

  if (guesses < randomNum) {
    console.log(" too low.. continue")
  } else if (guesses > randomNum) {
    console.log("too high ... continue ");
  } else {
    // It's not to low, not to high. It must be correct
    score++;
    console.log("great ... that is correct!!");
    randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
  }
}

console.log("game over ... your guess was right  " + scores + " times");
```